# How to copy an access table using c#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have a database with 2 tables
I want to make a copy of the data from the first table to the second one.
One table is empty and the other one has the data.

so far my code is:

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\\Dosimet\\dose_be.mdb");
conn.Open();
string copiar = "INSERT INTO DOSIMETROATIVO (SELECT * FROM DOSIMETRO)";
OleDbCommand cmdcopiar = new OleDbCommand(copiar, conn);
cmdcopiar.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

im getting an error on the **ExecuteNonQuery** (says syntax error on the INSERT INTO instruction)

both `DOSIMETROATIVO` (empty) and `DOSIMETRO` (with the data) are tables on the same database (dose_be.mdb).

Comment: Does the code not work?  What's the problem?

Comment: is this code not working?  If so, are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: it says sintax erron on the Insert Into instruction

Comment: are you able to execute the query directly against the db?

Comment: What happens when you eliminate those parentheses from your INSERT statement?

Comment: it works, thanks HansUp, it was the parentheses...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the parentheses from your `INSERT` statement.

```
INSERT INTO DOSIMETROATIVO SELECT * FROM DOSIMETRO
```